# Drag and drop, the drag element id and where to drop id

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm working with the drag and drop using HTML5 and JavaScript, I want to get the id of the dragged element and the id where to dragged.

The first part was easy, but getting the id where to drag that's my problem.

This is my code HTML :

```html
<div class="form-group" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event, this)" id="drop1" ondrop="getID(this, ev)" >
<label class="col-sm-12 control-label">Equipe 1</label>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="form-group"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<table>
   <tr>
       <td><img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="img/profile_small.jpg" /></td>
       <td><label class="control-label">Employé 4</label></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

and here the Javascript :

```js
<script>
            function allowDrop(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
            }

            function drag(ev) {
                ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
            }

            function drop(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
                ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
                alert(document.getElementById(data).textContent+" Dropped");
            }
</script>
```

Thank you

Comment: which id you want drag or drop

Comment: this one : i forgot to put it there sorry :

Comment: where are you want to drop it

Comment: i corrected the post, i want to drop it into another div

Comment: you want to drag "drag5" this div , but where you want to drop another div is not mention

Comment: refer this link   https://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: i want to drop it in "drop1", the first one

Comment: Thanks for accepting answer and Give me upvert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```html
<style>
#drag5
{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color:blue;
  width:300px;
}
#drop1
{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color:blue;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
}
</style>

<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>

<div class="form-group"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag5" >

<table>
   <tr>
       <td><img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ekut6zqo6VY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACk/6qR5GAaQ00I/photo.jpg?sz=32" /></td>
       <td><label class="control-label">Employé 4</label></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/>

<div id="drop1" class="form-group" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

<label class="col-sm-12 control-label">Equipe 1</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Put your  javascript function before your html @krn Rajput

Comment: @Mohamed Sadok Krichen : Your Issue is resolve or not

Answer (score -1):

The alert message will probably give you the answer.

```
    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        alert(ev.target.id + document.getElementById(data).id);
    }
```